# jMonkeyEngine - automatically mark others radio buttons

Tags: jmonkeyengine, nifty-gui

I want to create method who get radio button and marked this when other radio button will be marked. Here is my nifty gui example menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<nifty>
    <useControls filename="nifty-default-controls.xml"/>
    <useStyles filename="nifty-default-styles.xml"/>
    <screen id="ustawieniaWyswietlania" controller="PakietyPodstawowe.Kontroler.KontrolerUstawieńWyświetlania">
        <layer id="GLayer0" childLayout="center">
            <control id="r1" name="radioButtonGroup"/>
            <panel id="GPanel0" childLayout="absolute" width="100%" x="210" y="257" style="nifty-panel-simple" height="100%">
                <control name="radioButton" id="GRadioButton0" group="r1" x="193" y="236"/>
                <control name="radioButton" id="GRadioButton1" group="r1" x="327" y="244"/>
            </panel>
        </layer>
    </screen>
</nifty>
```

My method:

```
@NiftyEventSubscriber(pattern="GRadioButton.*")
public void setSelected(final String id, final RadioButtonStateChangedEvent event) {
        IO.drukujL(event.getRadioButton().getElement().getId());
        Element element = screen.findElementByName("GRadioButton1");
//      element.setMarkted(); this method I can't find
}
```

Maybe this problem is simply but I don't know how to mark automatically GRadioButton1 when GRadioButton0 is marked.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a different method to get access to the RadioButton control API.

Use something like:

```
RadioButton radioButton = screen.findNiftyControl("GRadioButton1", RadioButton.class);
radioButton.select();
```

You might want to read chapter "11 Controls" in the [Nifty GUI PDF Manual](https://github.com/void256/nifty-gui/tree/1.4/nifty-core/manual). And there is a [Radiobutton reference](https://github.com/void256/nifty-gui/wiki/Radiobutton) in the wiki and the [RadioButton JavaDoc](http://nifty-gui.sourceforge.net/projects/1.3/nifty-default-controls/apidocs/de/lessvoid/nifty/controls/RadioButton.html) might help as well.

Please note that the wiki was written for 1.3.x but most of the information should still be valid for 1.4.x